# Windows shell damaged? Basic tabs and buttons layout with Aero enabled

Tags: windows-7, shell

I would need little help from you.

This is first time I see something like this happen to shell in Windows 7, as you can see, tabs and buttons in some programs, or control panel (see screenshot) are like those in basic Windows theme.
Of course, there is selected 'Adjust for best appearance' in System Properties, so it's not making a problem, also Aero theme is enabled, which is obvious.

What could be solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, apply default windows 7 theme from `Appearance` panel.
Secondly, run `sfc /scannow` from command prompt.

One more thing, some programs are not designed for aero appearance. So, they will have non-aero UI even if windows is using aero UI. This can especially happen with file open/browse box.

Comment: Huh, I was kinda busy last days so I didn't checked site for replies. This doesn't help, at all...